# How can I change a text style via checkbox AND load text's current style upon click?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, input

I have the following HTML form:

```
  <form name="sampleText" id="sample-text">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples bolded" this-elem="h1" id="h1Sample" value="Level-1 Header Sample" />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples bolded" this-elem="h2" id="h2Sample" value="Level-2 Header Sample" />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples bolded" this-elem="h3" id="h3Sample" value="Level-3 Header Sample" />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples bolded" this-elem="h4" id="h4Sample" value="Level-4 Header Sample" />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples" this-elem="pageText" id="pageTextSample" value="Page Text Sample" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples underlined" this-elem="aLink" id="aLinkSample" value="Normal Link Sample" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples underlined" this-elem="aVisited" id="aVisitedSample" value="Visited Link Sample" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="textStyleSamples underlined" this-elem="aHover" id="aHoverSample" value="Hovered Link Sample" />
    <br />
    <input class="ubem" id="underline" type="checkbox" /><u>Underline</u>
    <input class="ubem" id="bold" type="checkbox" /><b>Bold</b>
    <input class="ubem" id="italic" type="checkbox" /><em>Italic</em>
  </form>
```

I want to be able to select each input and change the input text to underlined, bold, or italicized based on checking a checkbox. This I can do already, with the following jQuery:

```
$('.textStyleSamples').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
});

$('.ubem').change(function() {
    $('.textStyleSamples').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            if ($("#underline").prop("checked")) {
                $(this).addClass('underlined');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('underlined');
            }
            if ($("#bold").prop("checked")) {
                $(this).addClass('bolded');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('bolded');
            }
            if ($("#italic").prop("checked")) {
                $(this).addClass('italicized');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('italicized');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What I can't figure out, and where to put it, is the jQuery function that will check the appropriate boxes for each style when the input with those style is clicked. For example, when the input for H1 Sample is clicked, the checkbox for 'bold' should be checked.

I had this function already:

```
    $('.textStyleSamples').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('underlined')) {
                $('#underline').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $('#underline').prop('checked', false);
            }
            if ($(this).hasClass('bolded')) {
                $('#bold').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $('#bold').prop('checked', false);
            }
            if ($(this).hasClass('italicized')) {
                $('#italic').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $('#italic').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
```

But I can't figure out how to make it coexist with the previous function. Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: I tried to do this:

```
$('.ubem').change(function() {
    $('.ubem').each(function() {
        $('.textStyleSamples').each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).toggleClass('underlined');
                $(this).toggleClass('bolded');
                $(this).toggleClass('italicized');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and it turns all the classes on/off at once, which makes sense. If an input is bold, and the checkbox for 'bold' is checked when you click on the bold input, unchecking the checkbox for bold should remove the bold class from the input.

Comment: Why doesn't what you have work?  I copied everything and it seems to be working as expected?

Comment: I honestly don't know. If I click on h1 and try to remove the bolded class by unchecking the box for it, it stays bold.

Comment: Ok, let me look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you were having was with the .each inside of your $('.ubem').change() event.  Really, there is no reason for you to be using .each in either of your functions because I believe you have all of the data you need to perform the actions you want.

As you can see below, I've simplified and consolidated the javascript.  First, the $('.textStyleSamples') on click function listens to every object that has the textStyleSamples class on it already.  There is no need to use a .each to iterate over each text box.  I also have the checkbox sync happen in the same function.

For the checkbox change event, I have removed the .each as well and create a variable that finds the selected textbox and then updates the values for that, instead of trying to iterate over each one.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c7e0j5b/1/) to test it out.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$('.textStyleSamples').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');

    var underlined = $(this).hasClass('underlined');
    $('#underline').prop('checked', underlined);

    var bolded = $(this).hasClass('bolded');
    $('#bold').prop('checked', bolded);

    var italicized = $(this).hasClass('italicized');
    $('#italic').prop('checked', italicized);
});

$('.ubem').change(function() {
    var $thisElement = $(this)[0];
    var $selected = $('.selected');

    if ($thisElement.id === 'underline') {
        $selected.toggleClass('underlined', this.checked);
    } else if ($thisElement.id === 'bold') {
        $selected.toggleClass('bolded', this.checked);
    } else if ($thisElement.id === 'italic') {
        $selected.toggleClass('italicized', this.checked);
    }
});
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. I will study `.each()` more to understand it better. Thank you for your help, it works exactly how I wanted it to!

Comment: Updated the javascript to be even simpler.  Also, it's more of a understanding of the javascript overall.  When your checkbox is checked, you know you want to update the selected value, so just go and find and update the selected value vice versa when clicking on the textbox.  You know what classes have been enabled on the checkbox, so go and update the appropriate checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/bunad/3/edit)**

Actually if you **change your classes** to **match exactly the Checkboxes ID**

```
<input type="text" class="underline bold italic" value="Text..." />
```

**This is all you need:**

```
$('.textStyleSamples').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $(".ubem").prop("checked", function(){
    return $('.selected').attr('class').match(this.id); // compare . with #
  });
});

$('.ubem').click(function() {
  $('.selected').toggleClass(this.id, this.checked);
});
```

Quite simple, no?

<sub>Also I removed the `this-elem="aHover"` attribute from your HTML cause **it's invalid**. You should use `data-*` attributes instead like: `data-elem="aHover"`</sub>